# regex capturing with repeating pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to capture all parts of a string, but I can't seem to get it right.

The string has this structure: `1+22+33`. Numbers with an operator in between. There could be any number of terms.

What I want is `["1+22+33", "1", "+", "22", "+", "33"]`

But I get: `["1+22+33", "22", "+", "33"]`

I've tried all kinds of regexes, this is the best I've got, but it's obviously wrong.

```
let re = /(?:(\d+)([+]+))+(\d+)/g;
let s = '1+22+33';
let m;
while (m = re.exec(s))
  console.log(m);
```

Note: the operators may vary. So in reality I'd look for `[+/*-]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), like this:

```js
const input = '3+8 - 12'; // I've willingly added some random spaces

console.log(input.split(/\s*(\+|-)\s*/)); // Add as many other operators as needed
```

Answer (score 1):

Just thought of a solution: `/(\d+)|([+*/-]+)/g;`

Comment: This regex won't work as it has an unescaped delimiter in it. It will also match 1-+*/23 which I presume isn't really legal?

Comment: Right that multiplier is wrong. I've noticed that it depends on the regex engine whether or not you need to escape these operators in a class. I'm using this on node.js, and it works fine, but I guess it makes my code less portable.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to `split` on digits:

```js
console.log(
  "1+22+33".split(/(\d+)/).filter(Boolean)
);
```