# RegEx for capturing a repeating pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have the following regex from [regex capturing with repeating pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49717988/regex-capturing-with-repeating-pattern)

```
([0-9]{1,2}h)[ ]*([0-9]{1,2}min):[ ]*(.*(?:\n(?![0-9]{1,2}h).*)*)
```

It takes the following string

```
1h 30min: Title 
- Description Line 1
1h 30min: Title
- Description Line 1
- Description Line 2
- Description Line 3
```

And produces this as a result

```
Match 1:
  "1h 30min: Title 
  - Description Line 1"

      Group 1: "1h"
      Group 2: "30min"
      Group 3: "Title 
               - Description Line 1"

Match 2:
  "1h 30min: Title 
 - Description Line 1
 - Description Line 2
 - Description Line 3"

      Group 1: "1h"
      Group 2: "30min"
      Group 3: "Title 
               - Description Line 1
               - Description Line 2
               - Description Line 3"
```

---

I now have the matching `1h 30min` not always occur on a new line. So say I hade the following string

```
1h 30min: Title 
- Description Line 1 1h 30min: Title - Description Line 1
- Description Line 2
- Description Line 3
```

How can I modify the regex to get the following matched result?

```
Match 1:
  "1h 30min: Title 
  - Description Line 1"

      Group 1: "1h"
      Group 2: "30min"
      Group 3: "Title 
               - Description Line 1"

Match 2:
  "1h 30min: Title - Description Line 1
 - Description Line 2
 - Description Line 3"

      Group 1: "1h"
      Group 2: "30min"
      Group 3: "Title - Description Line 1
               - Description Line 2
               - Description Line 3"
```

I though removing the `\n` would do the trick but it just ends up matching everything after the first `1h 30min`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make this work with only minor changes, but the issue is that last part.  The general form of a [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) is this:

```
(.(?!notAllowed))+
```

so, using this pattern for your case, plus adding named groups for clarity:

```
(?<hours>[0-9]{1,2}h)[ ]*(?<minutes>[0-9]{1,2}min):\s*(?<description>(?:.(?!\dh\s\d{1,2}min))+)
```

PS: if you cannot turn on a "dot matches newline" mode, you may be able to [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544636/what-does-s-s-mean-in-regex-in-php) `[\s\S]` to simulate.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/u872xY/5/)

Comment: If you see https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed, you will notice that the `.` must be located *after* the negative lookahead. [See why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794).

Answer (score 2):

I can't solve it with minor changes.
So, I just offer my solution:

```
([0-9]{1,2}h) *([0-9]{1,2}min):[\s\S]*?(?=[0-9]{1,2}h|$)
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired output is quite difficult to match, yet not impossible.

I would do part of it, maybe the time and title part with regular expressions, if OK, then the rest with scripting.

Here, we can start with an expression similar to:

```
([0-9]{1,2}h)\s+([0-9]{1,2}min):\s+(Title)([\d\D]*?\d|.+)|[\s\S]*
```

or:

```
([0-9]{1,2}h)\s+([0-9]{1,2}min):\s+([A-Za-z\s]+)([\d\D]*?\d|.+)|[\s\S]*
```

```js
const regex = /([0-9]{1,2}h)\s+([0-9]{1,2}min):\s+(Title)([\d\D]*?\d|.+)|[\s\S]*/gm;
const str = `1h 30min: Title 
- Description Line 1 1h 30min: Title - Description Line 1
- Description Line 2
- Description Line 3`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]